# stringr:: functions drops or ignores locale

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am stuggeling with R and stringr. When performing str_trim, str_upper etc my danish characters are converted into unicode charaters:

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

Clean_String <- function(string) {
    #locale <- stri_locale_list()[grep("DK", stri_locale_list())]
    print(c("1:", string))
    string <- stringr::str_trim(string)
    print(c("2:", string))
    string <- stringr::str_to_upper(string, "da_DK")
    print(c("3:", string))
    return(string)
}

Clean_String("This IS a test with danish letters: ÆØÅ ..  ")
```

Calling Clean_String gives the following output:

```
[1] "1:" "This IS a test with danish letters: ÆØÅ ..  "
[1] "2:" "This IS a test with danish letters: ’\u009d\u008f .."
[1] "3:" "THIS IS A TEST WITH DANISH LETTERS: ’\u009d\u008f .."
[1] "THIS IS A TEST WITH DANISH LETTERS: ’\u009d\u008f .."
>
```

So i fails from line "2:". Applying the locale "da_DK" does not have an impact. I think I must be missing something obvious as all stringr:: functions has the same behavior.

I know I can use toupper. toupper keeps the locale. But I would like to use stringr functions and understand what i am doing wrong.

How do I keep the same locale/format on strings?

**[UPDATE]**
Seems like the issue was connected to R Tools for Visual Studio 0.4.20623.1711. I needed to specify "Code page" under R Tools->Options->Advanced->Code Page. It was set to (OS Default). Changing it to Western European (ISO) fixed it.

Comment: It is not reproducible with my locale as I get all  `"This IS a test with danish letters: ÆØÅ ..";  "THIS IS A TEST WITH DANISH LETTERS: ÆØÅ .."
[1] "THIS IS A TEST WITH DANISH LETTERS: ÆØÅ .."`  My locale settings as `locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252`

Comment: I get the same result as @akrun. my locales are: locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to finalize the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was connected to **R Tools for Visual Studio 0.4.20623.1711**.

It was necessary to specify "Code page" under *R Tools*->*Options*->*Advanced*->*Code Page*.

It was set to `(OS Default)`. Changing it to `Western European (ISO)` fixed it.